Why is the autofill text color not white in my form input?
I have created an HTML form and I am trying to set the text color of autofilled inputs to white. However, it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here is my code:


input:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000 inset !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
<form action="/submit-form" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>



Despite setting the color to white using color: #fff !important;, the autofill text remains black. How can I ensure that the autofill text color is white? Are there any known issues or additional CSS rules I need to apply to fix this?

Go here and here and make sure your browser has auto-fill enabled.

It may not be the most timely answer, but if an alternative using text-shadow, I hope it will be of some use.


input:-webkit-autofill {
  background-color: #000 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #000 inset !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px #000 inset !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 5px #fff;
}
<form action="/submit-form" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>



